# what happens to uialertview when app goes into bkgr

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uialertview

in my app I need to create a bunch of `UIAlertView` popups expecting user to respond to each of them at some moment of time. By definition `UIAlertView` is non modal, i.e. the logic  of my app continues to execute after making them. When the app would go into background would the popups be automatically saved? It looks like when user responds by clicking the button, correct popup responds even after app goes into bkgr and comes back. Does it mean that the `UIAlertView` popup ptrs are preserved during save/restore, ie can be reused after restore, OR, there is some mangling done to support clickedButtonByIndex:alert referring to correct popup?
Thanks. Victor

Answer (score 1):

UIAlertView inherits from UIView, as does say a scroll view. These user interface elements are all "saved" when your app goes into the background, and are not mangled in some way. When your app comes back into the foreground all your UI elements work the same.

Comment: Thanks, I this confirms my expectation. Regards, Victor

Answer (score 1):

FYI, this behavior has changed in iOS 4 (in the unlikely event that you're trying to support pre iOS 4): See the "Important" note in the "Overview" section of the [UIAlertView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html).

But, yes, your app is preserved, unless iOS has to shut it down, in which case all bets are off.

Comment: I think not to support pre 4.2 ios. Thank you for the clarification. Regards, Victor